# How to release HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped objects in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate, structuremap

When performing background tasks in a Windows Service I used `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` for storing intances of NHibernate ISessions.

Since within a Windows Server there isn't a HTTPContext, I'm wondering if only calling the `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()` is enough to release the ISession instance for that thread?

Comment: Have you tried this? What was the result?

Comment: I didn't think it was. I just gave it a try and got a NullReferenceException which I'm guessing is because there isn't a HttpContext. So No, that method is definitely not the right way to release the session.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out how to answer this question. The `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()` method exposed by the ObjectFactory is really concerned with the HttpContext and therefore web applications.

The HybridLifeCycle class from the Structuremap.Pipeline namespace allows to directly access cached objects inside the ThreadLocal storage and dispose them. Here is an example:

```
Action.For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<UnitOfWork>();
```

Above code registers the supplied type and caches its instances in the HttpContext or the ThreadLocal storage. It's always a good idea to inherite those types from IDisposable. Thus in this example UnitOfWork is also an IDisposable.

```
new HybridLifecycle().FindCache().DisposeAndClear();
```

Now to dispose cached objects regardsless of a web application or windows service the above line is sufficient to dispose the UnitOfWork instead of the `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()` method. I hope this helps someone.