# HttpContextScoped in StructureMap, ASP.NET throws null reference exception in background threads

Tags: asp.net, structuremap, httpcontext

I am using StructureMap for creating instance of DbEntities per request in ASP.NET.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<DbEntities>().HttpContextScoped().Use(CreateNewDbEntities); 
}
```

I have a bacgkround task running every 5 seconds which is trying to use DbEntities.

```
timer = new Timer(RunTasks, null, 1000 * 10/*time to wait until the first run*/, 1000 * 5/*time to wait between calls*/);
```

Now in method RunTasks I get null reference excption when I try to call GetDbEntities

```
private static void RunTasks(object sender)
{
    var muninService = GetDbEntities(); // Null reference excpetion
}

public static DbEntities GetDbEntities()
{
    return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<DbEntities>();
}
```

I am guessing this is becauase in a background thread I don't have access to httpcontextscope. Now I am new to structure map and I don't know were to start and fix this problem. Any ideas ?

Other methods that I use:

```
private static DbEntities CreateNewDbEntities()
{
    return new DbEntities();
}
```

Comment: There is a lifecycle called `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` that will fall back to per thread caching if a `HttpContext` is not available.

Comment: Running background threads inside an asp.net application is usually not a good plan.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am well informed about the downsides of running background threads inside asp.net application. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<DbEntities>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(CreateNewDbEntities); 
}
```

This should cache the instance per thread if a `HttpContext` is not available.

Comment: For `HttpContextScoped` instances, I run `ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()` in `Global.asax`'s `Application_EndRequest` method. Is there something similar in this case? Or should the task itself take care of that?

Comment: I didn't know how to do it before, but I managed to find a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424629/how-to-release-hybridhttporthreadlocalscoped-objects-in-structuremap). Basicly it comes down to `new HybridLifecycle().FindCache().DisposeAndClear();`